# Finding where PHP errors are logged on Ubuntu server?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, error-handling

I can't find the PHP error logs are on the ubuntu server.

Checking phpinfo() has "no value" for error_log. If I run a `locate error_log` I get nothing for the domain I am working with. This site is on a shared server, so I'm not sure I'll be able to change anything in php.ini -

Where are the PHP error logs?

Comment: I just do a comment, but why don't you write a function for logging with different loglevels? 

PS: Concerning your question; I guess you took a look at /var/log/apache?!

Comment: 500 is an appache error not a php one.

Comment: Right! 500 is an Apache! I forgot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This site is on a shared server

Then you need to **ask your web host** where the log file(s) are located.

It's entirely up to them where and how each virtual host has its logs written.

Answer (score 11):

Check the main Apache error log for the host:

`/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 2):

Usually on shared servers where virtual hosts are concerned, each vhost has its own unique `error_log` and `access_log` files.

On some hosts, these are typically in your home directory under a folder called logs.  If you don't see any directory in your home that looks like it stores logs, log into your hosting control panel and see if you can get access to them there.  For example, cPanel has a section called `logs`, where you can find an item called `Error Log` which would show you the contents of the Apache error log for your virtual host.